Find the electric field of an infinite sheet
I dont understand part of the solution to this problem

When attempting this problem on my own I didnt end up with the 2A thats comes from the integration of the differential area element. I just computed it as A being area of the "pillbox" which i thought would be the length x width x height of the "pillbox", I dont exactly understand why the side areas contribute nothing? I get that the at any point the horizontal components of the electrical field should cancel out since theres an equal and opposite contribution from each side of the infinite plane but i dont understand what that has to do with computing the integral of the area element.

The argument by symmetry here is important - because the plane is the same everywhere, the $E$ field can have no $x$ or $y$ components (if we take the infinite plane to be in the $xy$ plane). There are a few ways to argue this. One would be to simply observe that an infinite plane is not changed under rotations in the $xy$ plane (there are no preferred directions in the plane). As such, the $E$ field must also not change under such rotations, which implies that it has no $x$ or $y$ components.
This is the reason why the side walls of the box contribute nothing. They are parallel to the fieldlines, and as such $\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{a}=0$ over those regions.
This leaves only the top and bottom surfaces to compute the flux through. Because the electric field is perpendicular to the surfaces, the total flux through each will be $A|\mathbf{E}|$. Because there are two identical surfaces, the total flux leaving the pillbox will be twice this, $2A|\mathbf{E}|$.

$A$ is the area of the large rectangular face of the pillbox. We need the flux out of the pill box, this includes the flux out of the bottom side and the top side (hence $2A$). The area of the sides of the pillbox are perpendicular to the direction of the electric field. So there can't possibly be any flux through those surfaces.
